# Make the Header space a little shorter

Tags: header-footer

Basically I am trying to ensure that text on page two of any chapter respects 
the header. I sort of resolved this by including `\headsep = 45pt` (it ensures that the not-first chapter-pages respect the header.)

This ensures that text does not appear in the header section. The issue now is with the header length. It is too long and takes up too much space on the page. I would like to make it more compact and push it up on the page a bit further (out of the way of any text, and also to avoid having to include a headsep command (as above)).
Thanks in advance.

Regards, Michael

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{mathpazo}       % package to change fonts   
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage[margin=1in,bottom=0.5cm,paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage{amsmath}                
\usepackage{import}                 % For math stuff
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
\usepackage{chappg}             
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attrib}         
\usepackage{float}          
\usepackage[figurewithin=chapter]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}      % For tables spanning multiple pages
\usepackage{booktabs}       % For help formatting tables
\usepackage{multirow}       % For merged cells in a table
\usepackage{graphbox}       % Related to centering images vertically
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{pifont}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,% ensures ToC remains black if colour applied to chapter headings
linkcolor=black}

% IMPORTANT NOTE: YOU MUST USE THE LINE:               
% \graphicspath{{CHAPTERNAME/Images/}}                  
% OR SOMETHING SIMILAR AT THE TOP OF EACH CHAPTER FILE  
% FOR LATEX TO FIND YOUR IMAGES                         

\fancypagestyle{F1}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[c]{\scriptsize \vspace{0.1cm} Company Name}}
\fancypagestyle{F2}{\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize \vspace{0.1cm} \texttransparent{0.5}{Company Name}}\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}

% Setup page style, headers sets up non chapter pages
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{14pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1 pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\small \texttransparent{0.5}{Product}}
\fancyhead[R]{\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Tex.png}}\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize \vspace{0.1cm} \texttransparent{0.5} {Some Company Name}} 
\raggedbottom
\definecolor{ChapTitle}{RGB}{54,95,145}
\definecolor{SectTitle}{RGB}{79,129,189}
\allsectionsfont{\color{SectTitle}}
\chapterfont{\color{ChapTitle}}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, font={color=SectTitle}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headsep}{14pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\small\texttransparent{0.5}{Product Name}}
\fancyhead[R]{\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{Tex.png}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize \vspace{0.1cm} \texttransparent{0.5} {Product Name}}\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{14pt}{-8pt}

%Allows proper alignment in ToC in chapters with more than 9 sections
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em} 
    \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}
\makeatother

% For proper handling of the references
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\makeatletter % To make References a section but a chapter. This way, I like it more in my ToC and because there is no blank page created in front of the references.
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Note}{\textbf{\textcolor{SectTitle}{NOTE:} }}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage}

\thispagestyle{F2}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\color{ChapTitle}\filright\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptername \hspace{0.25em}\thechapter:} {0.2em} {}  
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\color{SectTitle}\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
\headsep=45pt  

\begin{document} 
 \begin{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
   \begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{Tex.png}  
     \vspace{1in}
   \end{flushright}     
   \Huge{\bfseries My First Book  \huge }
   \line(1,0){450}\\[0.1in]
   \textbf{\LARGE My Corporation \\}
   \textsc{\large \today}
   \begin{center}
    \vspace{3.5in}
    \underline{\textsf{\small Name and Address}} \\             
    \textsf{\small Other info. }
   \end{center} 
   \newpage
   \thispagestyle{F1}
  \end{center}
 \end{titlepage}

 \frontmatter
 \renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill \color{black}Contents \hfill}
 \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \setcounter{page}{1}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
 \tableofcontents    
 \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
 \mainmatter

 \chapter{Introduction}
 \lispum[1]

 \section{First Section}
 \lipsum[2]

 \section{First Section}
 \lipsum[3]

 \section{Second Section}
 \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: please try make your code minimal.

Comment: do you really need `fullpage` package? if no remove it and try with `\usepackage[hmargin=1in,bottom=0.5cm,top=1cm,paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}` i.e. add `top=1cm,` or what you like.

Comment: @touhami I you were able to understand the question, your comment probably answers it. Please write up an answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B your wish is my command

Answer (score 2):

If I understand one can do this in two step

1. remove `\usepackage{fullpage}`
2. edit the line `\usepackage[margin=1in, bottom=0.5cm, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}`
   [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) provides a very easy way to change the page layout.

---

So here I think one can type for example

```
\usepackage[margin=1in, bottom=0.5cm, top=1cm, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
```